# how to align arguments to functions in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, code-formatting

Say if I have the following:

```
func(arg1, arg2, arg3...)
func(longargarg1, longerarg2, arg3,...)
...
```

How do I align the arguments so that it's like following?

```
func(arg1       , arg2      , arg3...)
func(longargarg1, longerarg2, arg3,...)
...
```

[I can use M-x align-regex to align the first argument, but I cannot cook up with a suitable regex to align the rest of the arguments. Bonus point if the answer also take cares of the case when some arguments are strings with commas in them.]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Select the region, then:

```
C-u M-x align-regexp RET ,\(\s-*\) RET RET RET y
```

The regexp says to align commas with spaces following them.  The default value of 1 for the paren group to modify means insert spaces where the `\(\s-*\)` is, the default value of 1 for spaces to adjust means have one space after the longest expansion, and you want it repeated throughout the line.

Comment: Cool! I don't even know there is a more complex version of align-regexp. Note to self: read documentations... But is there a better version of the regexp that ignore the commas if they are inside a double quote pair? (emacs does not seem to have look-ahead/-behind type of regexps)

Comment: You could write your own alignment routine that uses the syntax table to determine which commas "count" in the regex.  I am not sure how to do that "easily", though.