# Viewing delimited columns in emacs

Tags: emacs, csv

Is anyone aware of an emacs mode or function that will reformat a buffer holding a delimited file such that each delimiter (e.g. tab) defines a "column" with the width of each column set to the longest entry?

I can reset the tab-width variable but that makes all columns equal width. I would much prefer variable-width columns if possible (like how a spreadsheet program like excel would display such a file after resizing the columns).

Comment: For cross-reference purposes, the following question demonstrates two other solutions to this question, using (a) Emacs' table.el library, and (b) SES (Simple Emacs Spreadsheet), which provides a proper spreadsheet application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273647/add-remove-column-spreadsheet-features-in-emacs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [Org mode's table editor](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Tables).

Comment: I had trouble connecting to http://orgmode.org/. An old copy of the manual can also be found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Built_002din-table-editor.html

Comment: org-mode is very good, but very slow on large files: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-08/msg00132.html So if your file is more than a few hundred lines it doesn't run very well.

Answer (score 5):

Org-mode as suggested by huaiyuan did just what I wanted.

To give an example to others, after I installed org-mode I found the following to work well.

Open a new file in org-mode `C-x C-f table.org` and then `M-x org-table-import` to import the delimited file, and you're done.

The `C-|` command didn't work for me to convert pre-existing buffer contents into a table, it just inserted a new table, but I don't know org-mode yet.

Comment: `C-|` works if the region is *active*, which (for me) means highlighting the region using the mouse, and then typing `C-|`.

Comment: @Trey: I think you mean `C-c |`?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your delimiter is `TAB`.  Mark the whole buffer, then:

```
C-u M-x align-regexp \(\s-*\)TAB RET RET RET y
```

Where `TAB` in there is an actual tab char.  See my similar answer here:

[how to align arguments to functions in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970759/how-to-align-arguments-to-functions-in-emacs/971435#971435)

Comment: Looks like you meant:
C-u M-x align-regexp RET \(\s-*\)TAB RET RET RET y

That works in emacs 23, but seems to give an error "not enough arguments for format string" in emacs 21 (which is still present on some systems that I use) .

To be really picky it also expands all the columns by a tab stop, but I guess a global replace would take care of that.