# Add/remove column spreadsheet features in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Given delimited data in the following format, how can I insert and delete columns?

```
abc|efg|123|xyz123abc|yes
xxx|bbb|cc|ddd|no
```

Say, for example, that I wanted to add a 3rd column with a default value of 1 and remove the 4th column so the data would look like this:

```
abc|efg|1|123|yes
xxx|bbb|1|cc|no
```

I was looking into org-mode tables as a starting point, however it puts extra spaces around the data.

```
| abc | efg | 123 | xyz123abc |
| xxx | bbb | cc  | ddd       |
|     |     |     |           |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just found out how to import data into SES (there are no "ses-import" functions, but it turns out you can simply yank tab-separated data), so this answer is even simpler than using table-capture :) (unless your data contains tabs, in which case you'll need to work around that).

SES is an actual spreadsheet application within Emacs. See its info node for details:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> `ses` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "ses")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

To process the data:

1. Convert your original data to TSV with, say, <kbd>M-%</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>
2. Kill that text (e.g. select region, then <kbd>C-w</kbd>)
3. Create a temporary buffer and change to ses-mode: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> `*ses*` <kbd>RET</kbd>
   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ses-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
   (and of course, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> for a description of ses-mode, and its keybindings)
4. Yank the data into the spreadsheet: <kbd>C-y</kbd>
5. Move point to the column to delete, and kill it with <kbd>M-k</kbd>
6. Copy the result back to the kill ring in TSV format: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>
   (i.e. `mark-whole-buffer` + `ses-export-tsv`)
7. Kill the *ses* buffer with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>
8. Yank the modified TSV data back into the original buffer with <kbd>C-y</kbd>
9. Convert the tabs back to `|`s with <kbd>M-%</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

Caveat: I'm actually having issues yanking into SES under my standard config, but this process works fine under `emacs -q`. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

As well as org-mode's table facilities, Emacs has some other table editing features, which will get you most of the way there.

```
abc|efg|123|xyz123abc|yes
xxx|bbb|cc|ddd|no
```

Selecting the region followed by
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `table-capture` <kbd>RET</kbd> `|` <kbd>RET</kbd> `$` <kbd>RET</kbd>  <kbd>RET</kbd> `1` <kbd>RET</kbd>

gives us:

```
+---+---+---+---------+---+
|abc|efg|123|xyz123abc|yes|
+---+---+---+---------+---+
|xxx|bbb|cc |ddd      |no |
+---+---+---+---------+---+
```

Now move point inside a cell of the column you wish to delete, and use
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `table-delete-column` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
+---+---+---+---+
|abc|efg|123|yes|
+---+---+---+---+
|xxx|bbb|cc |no |
+---+---+---+---+
```

'Unrecognising' the table will switch off the table editing mode, so that you can safely mess with the formatting.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `table-unrecognize-table` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Then it's just a matter of search-and-replace to revert back to the original format.

You can delete all the row separators by killing the first row with <kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd>, and the remainder with <kbd>M-%</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>)

```
|abc|efg|123|yes|
|xxx|bbb|cc |no |
```

Then you just need to clean up the row prefix and suffix, and the padding within cells:

<kbd>M-C-%</kbd> `+|` <kbd>RET</kbd> `|` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> (n.b. there's a space before the `+`)
<kbd>M-C-%</kbd> `^|\||$` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>

```
abc|efg|123|yes
xxx|bbb|cc|no
```

You could record the clean-up steps as a keyboard macro (or write a function) in order to execute them in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to update it manually (though that might not be what you're after):

Adding or deleting characters using rectangles:

```
cua-mode
<C-return> ;; cua-set-rectangle-mark on first row
;; create a rectangle one character wide from first to last rows
;; type '1|' to create your new column.
```

Record a macro to add/delete a column entry and repeat for the entire file.

Comment: Agreed, except the question has now been edited to indicate variable cell widths within columns, so rectangle editing no longer applies.