# Emacs C++-mode indenting for function declarations

Tags: emacs, indentation

The coding standards at my company have changed such that the function declaration

```
void foo( int a, float* b);
```

must now be written as:

```
void
foo(int    a,
    float* b);
```

Where both the type of the variable and the name of the variable must be vertically aligned.

I'm using emacs 23.2 with c++-mode.

This mode lines up each variable type but won't let me indent the variable names to match.

Is there a build in setting to allow this?

If there isn't, what do I need to turn off to allow me to freely indent my variable names?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970759/how-to-align-arguments-to-functions-in-emacs

Comment: What do you mean by "won't let me"? If you insert spaces before the variable names, what happens? Do they disappear?

Comment: @dfan I can insert spaces to make the names line up, but I'd rather just go to the name and hit tab until it lines up with the name above

Comment: @aaa that question is close but not quite there, atleast the proposed solution doesn't really do what I require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is `M-i` (`tab-to-tab-stop`).

This will move the cursor to the next tab stop.  The tab stops may be configured by the variable `tab-stop-list`, which defaults to every eight columns.  Note this will either insert spaces or actual TAB characters depending on the local variable `indent-tabs-mode`.  (Be careful to not confuse this with `tab-width`, which influences how actual TAB characters are displayed.)

This will not always make the param names in the lowest possible column, e.g., you may end up with

```
void
foo(int     a,
    float*  b);   // two spaces there
```

but note that this is somewhat more maintainable-- when adding a new param with a longer type name you won't necessarily have to go fix up the rest, you'll only have to if you cross a tab column.

Answer (score 1):

Select the lines with the arguments then <kbd>M-x align</kbd>

Comment: That doesn't work, it only aligns the variable type and not the variable name.  Thanks for trying though:)

Comment: @chollida: It does here with Emacs 23.2.  Maybe it's something in your config, try starting Emacs with -Q

Comment: thanks for the tip.  When I run M-x align it only aligns each line not each word in each line.  Thanks for trying:)  I appreciate it.